# why my observe value function to retrieve data from firebase database doesn't work for the first time?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am trying to make a login system using google account to firebase authentication.

if the user login using google account **for the first time**, then they have to pick their city domicile first before go to HomeVC otherwise they can go straight to homeVC.

To tackle this issue, first I try to get the data from firebase database. if the user has been login before, then they will have user database in my firebase. so, the result from `snapshot.value` from `observe` it will be stored to `userBasicInformation`.

if the user login for the first time then `userBasicInformation` should be nil. but I don't know why the line of code that retrieve the data from my firebase database below seems never be executed in the first time

```
Database.database().reference().child("users/\(userKM.uid)").reference().observe
```

here is the simplified code of this login system. I give print number to track the code. the print result is below

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import GoogleSignIn

//  variable that store user basic data (uid, fullname, email, domicile)
var userBasicInformation : [String:Any]?

// sign in using google account to Firebase Authenctication
Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (user, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("failed to create firebase user using google account")
                print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }

            print("user successfully logged into firebase")

            print("1")

            guard let userKM = user else { return }

             print("2")
            // retrieve User Basic data from firebase database
            Database.database().reference().child("users/\(userKM.uid)").reference().observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

                 print("3")

                if let valueDictionary = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] {
                    let userValue = User(dictionary: valueDictionary)

                    let userInformation : [String:Any] = [

                        "uid" : userValue.uid,
                        "fullname" : userValue.fullname,
                        "email" : userValue.email,
                        "domicile" : userValue.domicile
                    ]

                    userBasicInformation = userInformation

                } else {
                     print("4")
                    // if there is no snapshott.value (no database for certain uid) then set to nil. it means user logged in using gmail forthe first time
                    userBasicInformation = nil
                }

            }) 

            // if user has signed up before then send to mainTabBar (it means he/she has picked a city), otherwise pickCity first
            // if the user sign Up for the first time, then userBasicInformation will be nil because there is no user default available

            if userBasicInformation == nil {

                 print("5")

                // save user data to Firebase Database
                let userX = User(uid: userKM.uid, fullname: userKM.displayName!, email: userKM.email!)
                userX.save(completion: { (error) in

                    if error != nil {
                       print(error!)
                    }

                })

                // assign Value to superGlobal Variable
                userBasicInformation = [
                    "uid" : userX.uid as Any,
                    "fullname" : userX.fullname as Any,
                    "email" : userX.email as Any,
                    "domicile" : userX.domicile as Any
                ]


              self.pickCity()

            } else {
                 print("6")
              self.goToMainTabBar()
            }         
        }        
    }
```

here is the result from my debugging area

> - user successfully signin into google
> - user successfully logged into firebase
> - 1
> - 2
> - 5
> - 3

i don't understand why '3' which is 'retrieving data from firebase database' using observe seems never be executed first

i expect 1 -> 2 -> **3 -> 5** , 
but i got 1 -> 2 -> **5 -> 3**

thats why `userBasicInformation` always be nil if i restart the simulator

why my observe value doesn't work for the first time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is obvious.

Your execution of              `Database.database().reference().child("users/\(userKM.uid)").reference().observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in`

is async operation and it will executed after response form your request

while you are

checking `if userBasicInformation == nil {` condition next to the that async block `child("users/\(userKM.uid)")` , so it will executed first. (It will not wait for your firebase request `child("users/\(userKM.uid)")` to finish)

To Fix this Put all the `if userBasicInformation == nil {` and `else` block in the your firebase request block.

Hope it is helpful to you

**EDIT\UPDATE**

I don't understand why you are checking `if userBasicInformation == nil {`      after putting this stuff inside   `users/\(userKM.uid)"` you don't need to check it is nil or not

if you wan't to user to login automatically if he did before then

in `viewDidLoad` put

```
  GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signInSilently()

    Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in
        if user != nil {
         // HERE YOU CAN  PERFORM ANYTHING LIKE SAVING TO USERDEFAULT OR ANYTHING AFTER USER LOGGED IN
            UserDefaults.standard.setValue(user?.uid, forKeyPath: "uid")

            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "CurrentlyLoggedIn", sender: nil)

        }
    }
```